# Is it possible to have a single unique index for multiple rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to have a single unique index for multiple rows in pandas? 
Example:

```
index country value
1 NL 'hi'
2 NL 'wet'
3 SWE '4'
4 SWE 'maybe'
```

So, in this example I cannot set NL as an index because it's not unique. Is it not possible to have multiple rows for a index in pandas?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be unique in that case.

Comment: pandas does not require that values in the index are unique, so you *could* set the country column as the index (though this is not always advisable). However, it sounds like you're possibly looking for a [multiindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing).

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely set column `country` as the index in pandas. Indexes do not have to be unique. You could then grab all the rows for the value `NL` with the `.loc` operator.

```
df = df.set_index('country')
df.loc['NL']
```

From your comments below try this first with your original dataframe (no setting index).

```
df.groupby('country')['value'].apply(list).to_json())
```

Output

```
{"NL":["'hi'","'wet'"],"SWE":["'4'","'maybe'"]}
```

Comment: Alright, now I remember again why I wanted to do this. So setting the index is no problem at all. When I want to convert it to JSON however with the orient='index' it gives this error:

Comment: ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want see the edited answer above.