# What are the possible causes of this df.drop() behavior in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` of which `df2` is a subset.  When I try to drop rows in `df` based on the index values of `df2`, I get some funny math as below.  What might be causing such behavior? Am I completely misunderstanding how `.index` works?

```
print(df.index)
    
Int64Index([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ... 
    353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362], dtype='int64', length=4748)
```

```
print(df2.index)
    
Int64Index([ 0, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 15, 17, 18, ... 
    106, 123, 130, 136, 196, 217, 220, 227, 232, 237], dtype='int64', length=448)
```

```
df = df.drop(index = df2.index)
print(df.index)

Int64Index([ 63, 65, 67, 74, 76, 78, 83, 84, 85, 87, ... 
    352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361], dtype='int64', length=2116)
```

Comment: What is `chargebacks` in this context?

Comment: @Yehuda Sorry. Edited. That's the actual name of df2 (purchases that got refunded).

Comment: what exactly is confusing? your indexes don't seem to be unique, so math won't add up unless you're including counts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the numbering system, it looks like there are multiple records with the [same index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41209697/7287543). If that's the case, dropping, for example, `106` because it is in `df2` may result in multiple records being dropped from `df`. Check on the duplicates in your dataframes, at least in the indices.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for taking the time to look at this.  I was building a dataframe from multiple CSV files and used `pd.concat()` adding the `ignore_index=True` parameter fixed it perfectly.